# How to show full text for options of ionic select button?

Tags: html, ionic-framework

I have added a ionic select button in the page. The option will show a long string, I hope to it can show full text string, but the string is truncated with dot-dot-dot as below:[image]

My code is like:

```
<ion-item *ngIf="select == 'trip'">
    <ion-label> Select Trip </ion-label>
    <ion-select text-wrap>
      <ion-option *ngFor="let subtrip of trips" value = {{subtrip.tripid}}> {{subtrip.startTime}} - {{subtrip.stopTime}} </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

I have tried add text-wrap in the html, but it doesn't work... Can you help?

Answer (score 2):

For Ionic 4, every option inside `ion-select` needs to be wrapped inside `ion-select-option`. Trying out `interface="action-sheet"` will show the full text of options. The [default](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select#properties) interface is `alert`.

```
<ion-item>
 <ion-label>Food</ion-label>
  <ion-select interface="action-sheet" [(ngModel)]="food">
   <ion-select-option [value]="Burger">BurgerBurgerBurgerBurgerBurgerBurgerBurger</ion-select-option>
   <ion-select-option [value]="Sandwich">SandwichSandwichSandwichSandwichSandwichSandwich</ion-select-option>
   <ion-select-option [value]="Salad">SaladSaladSaladSaladSaladSaladSalad</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>
```

Default `alert` interface
[image: Using default <code>alert</code> interface]

`action-sheet` interface
[image: Using <code>action-sheet</code> interface]

Answer (score 0):

So if this is your template (html):

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Toppings</ion-label>
        <ion-select [(ngModel)]="toppings" multiple="true">
            <ion-option>BaconBaconBaconBaconBaconBaconBaconBaconBacon</ion-option>
            <ion-option>Black OlivesBaconBaconBaconBaconBaconBaconBacon</ion-option>
            <ion-option>Extra CheeseBaconBaconBaconBaconBaconBaconBacon</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

And you want to ensure no-wrap behavior you can not apply text-wrap to ionic components and hope it will support this behavior out of box unfortunately.

Normally you want to go to your Chrome Dev Tools > Elements and see what CSS rules are inherited and applied to your component (ion-select in this case):
[image]

Now depending on which platform style you are using (ios or md) you need to apply changes to this class (in case of ios used like in my case):

```
page-tutorials {
    .no-scroll .scroll-content {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
.alert-ios .alert-md .alert-checkbox-label {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```

Please note you need to add such class overriding outside of your page component's css (as above) to make it work.

Comment: Alright you can use md then, I will update this post now. You need to add class for material design - .alert-md. See updated answer

Answer (score -3):

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="radioGroup">
<ion-item>
  <ion-label text-wrap>RadioButtonText</ion-label>
  <ion-radio checked="false" value="value"></ion-radio>
</ion-item>
```

This should work fine for you

Comment: I forgot to close </ion-list>

Comment: did you try it? it won't work. Also in the question the code is about ion-select component.